# How to close STOMP Connection / Session from Java Server?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I am building a java STOMP server, and I would like to evict the client from the server side after a period of time.

How does one close a websocket session / websocket connection from the server side?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: No, I don't think there is one.  Seems like Spring has abstracted STOMP to the point of being mostly useless.